HTML content not rendering properly when creating email template by getting it from contact property in Hubspot
The Issue:
I'm saving some personalized HTML content for each contact in a custom "Rich Text" type property column.
I want the content to render as it should honoring the HTML it has (the paragraph and anchor tags, etc.) in the template where we add the personalized token.
What is happening is, the content comes as is. With all the HTML tags intact and visible (<p>...</p>, <a href="...">...</a>, etc.)
What am I doing wrong and what can I do to correct it?
Or is there something else I should try?
Things I have tried:
I have tried using the option to add a personalized token, i have also just mentioned it as {{contact.property_name}}, I have also tried to use the HTML module and mention the token there, I have used the Design Tools as well to create a purely HTML asset that I can then use to create a template but to no avail. Everything resulted in the same issue.
Expectations vs Reality:

Contact



...
property_name
...




...
<p>Hey,</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Donec commodo interdum velit vitae sollicitudin. Nulla.</p><p><a href="_some_hyperlink_">Lorem ipsum dolor.<a></p><br><p>Regards,</p><p>Company Name<p>
...







Template
...
{{contact.property_name}}
...




Expected outcome
...
Hey,
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Donec commodo interdum velit vitae sollicitudin. Nulla.
Lorem ipsum dolor
Regards,
Company Name
...




Actual outcome
...
<p>Hey,</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p><p>Donec commodo interdum velit vitae sollicitudin. Nulla.</p><p><a href="_some_hyperlink_">Lorem ipsum dolor.<a></p><br><p>Regards,</p><p>Company Name<p>
...



